# How to make Qt MainWindow always on top AND above start menu in Windows 11

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm trying to make a widget tool that stays above EVERYTHING.

Following the other stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747804/how-can-i-put-my-qt-application-mainwindow-always-above-the-taskbar-in-windows), I set the flag

```cpp
setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```

and use a timer to constantly `raise` the window.

Now it can stay above all normal windows and other always-on-top windows. But it will still get blocked if the Start menu is open.

Comment: It's a hint, right?  Guess what happens when another window *also* asks to be on top. That's what [the link to Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253) in the answers were about.

Comment: Short answer: it cannot be done. See the link posted by @BoP.

Comment: There is at least one type of widget that is on top of the start menu reliably. That is XBox Game Bar Widgets https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/game-bar/api/api-overview . If you pin them, then they are on top of the start menu.

Comment: @PeterT So maybe there is "secretly" a different set of rules for UWP applications (or even just XBox Game Bar Widgets)? I just tested that my application cannot be on top of the XBox Game Bar Widget.